# Consider defining a bean for jpa repository

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, javabeans

My project structure is as follows:

java/com.company.foo/container/configuration/

This folder contains

```
@ComponentScan({"com.company.foo.module.project",
        "com.company.foo.module.user"})
@Configuration
@EnableScheduling
@Import(value = {
        SecurityConfiguration.class})
public class ApplicationContextConfiguration {
}
```

My ResourcePlannerApplication is in this folder:

java/com.company.foo/container/

and has following annotations:

```
@Import({ApplicationContextConfiguration.class})
@SpringBootApplication
```

Now I have two modules project and user with both the same structure:

java/com.company.foo/module/user/dao/

This folder contains:

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<UserEntity, Long> {
    UserEntity findByUsername(String username);
}
```

now when I start the app it tells me:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.company.foo.module.user.dao.UserRepository' in your configuration.

I'm not seeing the problem because the ComponentScan is scanning all the folders?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JPA repositories are not picked up by component scans since they are just interfaces whos concrete classes are created dynamically as beans by Spring Data provided you have included the @EnableJpaRepositories annotation in your configuration:

```
@ComponentScan({"com.company.foo.module.project",
        "com.company.foo.module.user"})
@Configuration
@EnableScheduling
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.company.foo.module.user")
@Import(value = {
        SecurityConfiguration.class})
public class ApplicationContextConfiguration {
}
```

Comment: So I need to add something like @EntityScan(basePackages = {"com.company.foo.module.project.dao")
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"com.company.foo.module.project.dao"}) ?

Comment: Yeah, I updated my answer a little to add the package to the annotation

Answer (score 0):

Plog's answer is correct. 
I just want to add that, similar solution is applicable for Mongo Repositories as well (where we have interface as a repository). 
Suppose, repository package is:

```
package com.example.respository;
```

Enable mongo repositories in spring application code, like below:

```
@EnableMongoRepositories("com.example.repsoitory")
```